# How to flood fill with Color of pattern image in swift?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uibezierpath, flood-fill, scanline

- I have achieved to flood fill on the close boundary with solid color.
- Now I am trying to fill close boundary with UIColor but it is pattern image color (Pattern color).
- I also try to get points of close area where i tap and fill that area with use of bezier path, but it took too much time to get an array of close boundary area points.
- Please help me to achieve to fill pattern on UIImage object to specific close boundary area.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? you want the coding or the algorithm? Can you share a sample image?

Comment: Sure, i have A clipart, i wanted to fill any specific area with close i.e with black border, tap on that area and that area should be fill with pattern, like flood fill

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
let patternColor = UIImage(patternImage: <your UIImage>)
```

Comment: This is not an answer, what i am looking for, i mentioned i wanted to fill pattern on UIImage object to specific close boundary area.